# Printing a datetime, with timezone, but excluding the timezone name

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

I have a datetime object that I've created like so:

```
dt = datetime(2023, 9, 18, 22, 30, 0, tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=9)))
```

This corresponds to September 18th, 2023 at 10:30PM JST. I want to print this datetime like this:

> 2023-09-18 22:30:00+09:00

I attempted the following options:

```
dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z")  # 2023-09-18 22:30:00UTC+09:00
dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")  # 2023-09-18 22:30:00+0900
```

Neither of these is the format I want, and now I either have to remove `UTC` from the first one or add a colon to the third-to-last position in the second one. Is there a way to get the output I want without having to resort to string manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [isoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) with date/time `sep` set to space and a `timespec` of seconds:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

dt = datetime(2023, 9, 18, 22, 30, 0, tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=9)))

print(dt.isoformat(" ", timespec="seconds")
# 2023-09-18 22:30:00+09:00
```

Comment: I had to look up `isoformat` but this does exactly what I need it to.

Answer (score 3):

> *Is there a way to get the output I want without having to resort to string manipulation?*

You can do that by simply casting your `dt` to [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.__str__) :

```
print(str(dt)) # which gives 2023-09-18 22:30:00+09:00
```

Comment: Weird. I've been printing `datetime`s for days and I didn't notice this. Nice answer